# jQuery script conflict with Drupal 7's AJAX?

Tags: jquery, drupal-7

I added the "Magic line" effect to menu but it's causing problems in Admin interface. http://screencast.com/t/HxTs3ZLlT Button shown doesn't open inline settings as it should.

When overlay is loaded Firebug shows error:

$("#main-menu-links .active a").position() is null

Full screenshot of console: http://screencast.com/t/im1NKS025gJ9

And the script itself is called from .info file :

```
(function ($) {

    Drupal.behaviors.magicLine = {
        attach: function(context) {

            // Lava Lamp Meny Effect

            var $el, leftPos, newWidth,
                $mainNav = $("#main-menu-links");

           $mainNav.append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");
           var $magicLine = $("#magic-line", context);

            $magicLine
                .width($("#main-menu-links li.active").width())
                .css("left", $("#main-menu-links li.active a").position().left)
                .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
                .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());

            $("#main-menu-links li a").hover(function() {
                $el = $(this);
                leftPos = $el.position().left;
                newWidth = $el.parent().width();
                $magicLine.stop().animate({
                    left: leftPos,
                    width: newWidth
                });
            }, function() {
                $magicLine.stop().animate({
                    left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
                    width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
                });
            });
        }
    };


})(jQuery);
```

I'm not a programmer so I have no clue how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

The console message: $("#main-menu-links .active a").position() is null

typically means that jQuery could not find that element (an anchor element with id="main-menu-links" and class="active"). Are you sure the active class is being given to one of your main menu links?

Comment: I got that for other pages that were not marked as "active" and fixed it earlier, but in this case Admin uses modal window so "active" class remains there.